# Best practice for storing constant stream of data

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database

The main requirement for my current project is to receive, parse and store millions of radio messages per day. This means many messages per second are processed. At the moment the method of storing the parsed messages uses simple a `SqlCommand` and `ExecuteNonQuery` for each individual message.

Seeing as each the project consists of multiple `TcpClient`s reading in on separate threads there will be many concurrent instances of the below block being executed:

```
query.Append(string.Format("INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2})", this._TABLE_, col, val));
sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query.ToString(), sql);
sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I understand an alternative may be to cache the parsed messages and at scheduled times perform a bulk insert.

Using the Entity Framework is an option, but probably overkill for the simple requirements.

The program requires a persistent connection 24 hours per day and therefore never closes the db connection.

So my question is, how reasonable is my current approach? Should I close and open connections for each message? Or continue using a global db connection shared and passed by reference?

Comment: What you need to ask yourself, and tell us the answer, is how would you do this if you did not have a database and where just saving the data on the disk? I ask because if you are using a newer version of SQL you may be able to use a [FILESTREAM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx) column and have a similar model in the database.

Comment: I'm currently using 2012 although I have 2008 installed too. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Why not store the messages as files on the file system, or on a central file system, then just insert pointers into your SQL database to identify where the message files are? Even files stored on the file system can be retrieved from SQL like a query using filestreaming.

Comment: @Brian that is exactly what the FILESTREAM column in SQL 2008 and newer does, but you also get transactional support.

Comment: Yeah, you answered the question a few minutes before I did. I think Lee would do well saving his messages on the file system. He can crank out some multi-threaded program to write the files and insert a quick row in SQl without breaking a sweat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you using Sql Server to as your data store? I don't mean this rhetorically. I mean, what are the requirements for querying the data after it has been inserted? Will there ever be updates to existing data? Deletions? Are there normalized tables somewhere in the near future for this data?

These answers will inform the reasonableness of your current approach.

> The program requires a persistent connection 24 hours per day and
>   therefore never closes the db connection.

You should open and close the db connection in your code regardless. ADO.NET pools the connections so you don't have to keep the connection open manually:

```
using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection("...")) {
    query.Append(string.Format("INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2})", this._TABLE_, col, val));
    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query.ToString(), sql) {
        sql.Open();
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: I wondered about `using` thanks for your suggestions. To answer your questions: the database tables effectively act as warehouses. The messages are constantly being inserted and in the future will be used to generate reports. The data will also be truncated once it reaches a certain age (6 or 12 months). As for updates, the syntax for the messages may change (meaning tables will have to be updated) as well as additional types of messages. If not sql what would you recommend? Oracle is being used by other teams here.

Comment: @Lee "If the other teams jumped off a bridge would you too?" Don't fulfill your design requirements by what the "other teams" use. Use what is the proper solution for your design requirements.

Comment: Good advice :) by the way, in your above code do you not need to `open()` the connection? Is that within the `using` context?

Comment: @Lee It depends on if you are using a SqlCommand or another class, Command needs you to open it, things like SqlDataAdapter I think will open it for you.

Comment: You do need to open it. I have edited the code.

About your first follow-up Q: It will be slow to run reports from the table without indexes. Conversely, indexes on the table will hurt the `INSERT` performance. This table is really part of an OLTP database (OnLine Transaction Processing), albeit with only one kind of transaction. The data should be bulk-inserted into a reporting database (your warehouse).